# Get ID value from Angular scope and use in statment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a array of objects that are displayed in my scope once selected via two drop down selection boxes, first box to select name second to select format.

example of a object

```
 {
    "name": "tim",
            "format": [
                {"Fname": "a", "id": "1"},
                {"Fname": "b", "id": "2"},
                {"Fname": "c", "id": "3"}
            ]
        },
```

and I send it to the scope using

```
 $scope.productTypeChange = function () {
        $scope.formats = $scope.productsandformats.find(ps => ps.name == $scope.formData.ProductType.name)
}
```

I get a pint out on my scope like

```
 {"ProductType":{"name":"tim"},"formatType":{"Fname":"a","id":"1"}}
```

I then want have a if statement based on the ID value printed in the scope, I have tried so far to get the ID value, however it dose not seem to work, Is this the correct way to get the ID >

```
$scope.setCanvasSize = function() {
    divHeight = $('.image-builder').height();
    if ($scope.formData.ProductType.name.id = 1) {
        // Aratio = 0.67;
        Aratio = 2;
    } else if ($scope.formData.ProductType.name.id = 2) {
        Aratio = 0.56;
    } else if ($scope.formData.ProductType.name.id = 3) {
        divHeight = divHeight / 1.5;
        Aratio = 2;
    } else if ($scope.formData.ProductType.name.id = 4) {
        Aratio = 0.67;
    } else {
        Aratio = 1
    }
    canvas.setHeight(divHeight - 15);
    canvas.setWidth((divHeight - 15) * Aratio);
    canvas.renderAll();
    $scope.position();
};
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Il update the question for you and others

Comment: U want to get id ?

Comment: the ID value eg 1 , 2 or 3

Comment: I have added the answer to your requirement

Comment: Ok thanks @Vivz ill try your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the object wrongly. If

```
$scope.formats={"ProductType":{"name":"tim"},"formatType":{"Fname":"a","id":"1"}};
```

Then to get id you have to access the object like this

```
$scope.formats.formatType.id
```

You also have to check correctly in if statements. In your question you are assigning values instead of comparison. So, it should be like this:

```
if($scope.formats.formatType.id=="1"){
//do calculations
}
```

Comment: so my If statement would be  if `($scope.formats.formatType.id = 1) {somthing}` ?

Comment: It should be  if ($scope.formats.formatType.id == "1") since the ids are strings as seen from ur question

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you accessing the "value" using the array (Assuming, since you're using find) as in "$scope.formData.ProductType.name.id" instead of accessing the value withing "$scope.formats.formatType.id" (That you already filtered).

Also, in the filtered variable you don't have a format that match the kind of "$scope.formData.ProductType.name.id", instead you have to access the variable like this -> "$scope.formats.formatType.id"